# How to upgrade this Crowdsale contract (from DappUniverse)

Tags: solidity, upgrading

i'm trying to compile this code (from DappUniversity: https://github.com/dappuniversity/ico_irl/blob/master/contracts/DappTokenCrowdsale.sol) but with the new version of OpenZeppelin, that's use at least "pragma 0.5.0"-

Of course if you try to compile it on Remix, you will get a lot of error, and that's why it needs to be updated.

Here is the whole code:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/PausableToken.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/TokenTimelock.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/WhitelistedCrowdsale.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";

contract DappTokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, WhitelistedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {

  // Track investor contributions
  uint256 public investorMinCap = 2000000000000000; // 0.002 ether
  uint256 public investorHardCap = 50000000000000000000; // 50 ether
  mapping(address => uint256) public contributions;

  // Crowdsale Stages
  enum CrowdsaleStage { PreICO, ICO }
  // Default to presale stage
  CrowdsaleStage public stage = CrowdsaleStage.PreICO;

  // Token Distribution
  uint256 public tokenSalePercentage   = 70;
  uint256 public foundersPercentage    = 10;
  uint256 public foundationPercentage  = 10;
  uint256 public partnersPercentage    = 10;

  // Token reserve funds
  address public foundersFund;
  address public foundationFund;
  address public partnersFund;

  // Token time lock
  uint256 public releaseTime;
  address public foundersTimelock;
  address public foundationTimelock;
  address public partnersTimelock;

  constructor(
    uint256 _rate,
    address _wallet,
    ERC20 _token,
    uint256 _cap,
    uint256 _openingTime,
    uint256 _closingTime,
    uint256 _goal,
    address _foundersFund,
    address _foundationFund,
    address _partnersFund,
    uint256 _releaseTime
  )
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
    public
  {
    require(_goal <= _cap);
    foundersFund   = _foundersFund;
    foundationFund = _foundationFund;
    partnersFund   = _partnersFund;
    releaseTime    = _releaseTime;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Returns the amount contributed so far by a sepecific user.
  * @param _beneficiary Address of contributor
  * @return User contribution so far
  */
  function getUserContribution(address _beneficiary)
    public view returns (uint256)
  {
    return contributions[_beneficiary];
  }

  /**
  * @dev Allows admin to update the crowdsale stage
  * @param _stage Crowdsale stage
  */
  function setCrowdsaleStage(uint _stage) public onlyOwner {
    if(uint(CrowdsaleStage.PreICO) == _stage) {
      stage = CrowdsaleStage.PreICO;
    } else if (uint(CrowdsaleStage.ICO) == _stage) {
      stage = CrowdsaleStage.ICO;
    }

    if(stage == CrowdsaleStage.PreICO) {
      rate = 500;
    } else if (stage == CrowdsaleStage.ICO) {
      rate = 250;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @dev forwards funds to the wallet during the PreICO stage, then the refund vault during ICO stage
   */
  function _forwardFunds() internal {
    if(stage == CrowdsaleStage.PreICO) {
      wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    } else if (stage == CrowdsaleStage.ICO) {
      super._forwardFunds();
    }
  }

  /**
  * @dev Extend parent behavior requiring purchase to respect investor min/max funding cap.
  * @param _beneficiary Token purchaser
  * @param _weiAmount Amount of wei contributed
  */
  function _preValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    super._preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, _weiAmount);
    uint256 _existingContribution = contributions[_beneficiary];
    uint256 _newContribution = _existingContribution.add(_weiAmount);
    require(_newContribution >= investorMinCap && _newContribution <= investorHardCap);
    contributions[_beneficiary] = _newContribution;
  }


  /**
   * @dev enables token transfers, called when owner calls finalize()
  */
  function finalization() internal {
    if(goalReached()) {
      MintableToken _mintableToken = MintableToken(token);
      uint256 _alreadyMinted = _mintableToken.totalSupply();

      uint256 _finalTotalSupply = _alreadyMinted.div(tokenSalePercentage).mul(100);

      foundersTimelock   = new TokenTimelock(token, foundersFund, releaseTime);
      foundationTimelock = new TokenTimelock(token, foundationFund, releaseTime);
      partnersTimelock   = new TokenTimelock(token, partnersFund, releaseTime);

      _mintableToken.mint(address(foundersTimelock),   _finalTotalSupply.mul(foundersPercentage).div(100));
      _mintableToken.mint(address(foundationTimelock), _finalTotalSupply.mul(foundationPercentage).div(100));
      _mintableToken.mint(address(partnersTimelock),   _finalTotalSupply.mul(partnersPercentage).div(100));

      _mintableToken.finishMinting();
      // Unpause the token
      PausableToken _pausableToken = PausableToken(token);
      _pausableToken.unpause();
      _pausableToken.transferOwnership(wallet);
    }

    super.finalization();
  }

}
```

Comment: I think it is a good exercise. Do you have any particular issue? The difficult part is to update OpenZeppelin which require some changes how thinks were done (ie some contract variables were made private in the new version).

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a Crowdsale I recommend that you look at the current OpenZeppelin guide on Crowdsales for the different properties that you may want to use.
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales